# Use a single server to relay external RDP connections to workstations

Tags: windows, firewall, rdp

I have a large number of computers external to our network that want to access their workstations via RDP. I was hoping I could set up a single server that could manage/route external RDP connections to their workstations on our LAN. Are there any server tools to achieve this? VPN is not a possibility at this facility, and I don't want to deal with managing firewall changes to each workstation every time a person needs/doesn't need access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to setup a  Remote Desktop Gateway. No VPN is required.

Remote Desktop Gateway is a service that enables people to securely log into their company's Windows computers from any Internet-connected device that's running a Remote Desktop client app. That can be a Windows PC, a Mac, a tablet, or even a smartphone.

Comment: Been playing around with that and it looks like it's going to work. Thanks!